# Moveit2 'planning plugin name is empty' error when creating a new planning pipeline

Tags: ros2, moveit

I am trying to create a ROS2 node to send a goal pose to Moveit2 to initiate planning when working with 6 dof robot arm, xarm6. I am following the tutorial code from moveit2 like [here](https://moveit.picknik.ai/main/doc/examples/motion_planning_pipeline/motion_planning_pipeline_tutorial.html#expected-output).

I am currently launching a xarm ros2 driver node, which launches rviz2 with the current state of robot and I can drag the end-effector around to plan and execute in the real robot. But i am trying to do this through my node where I send a goal pose of the end-effector that plan.

When I am launching my node, the error is

```
[INFO] [1704408295.119143854] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'UF_ROBOT'...
[INFO] [1704408295.119154153] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[WARN] [1704408295.213406999] [moveit_ros.robot_model_loader]: No kinematics plugins defined. Fill and load kinematics.yaml!
[INFO] [1704408295.477361119] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[INFO] [1704408295.483905941] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[INFO] [1704408295.483918325] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[INFO] [1704408295.484130321] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[INFO] [1704408295.484346986] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[WARN] [1704408295.484566015] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[ERROR] [1704408295.484576395] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[INFO] [1704408295.681676533] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[INFO] [1704408295.681920179] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[ERROR] [1704408295.681941450] [xarm_move_client_node]: here
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Planning plugin name is empty. Please choose one of the available plugins: chomp_interface/CHOMPPlanner, ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner, pilz_industrial_motion_planner/CommandPlanner, stomp_moveit/StompPlanner
[ros2run]: Aborted
```

and I have isolated that the error comes from this line of my code
`planning_pipeline::PlanningPipelinePtr planning_pipeline(new planning_pipeline::PlanningPipeline(robot_model, node_handle_, "xarm6"));` as given to me by the tutorial.

But the error got me wondering where the code is reading Planning plugin name from so that I can fill that in myself? There is a ompl_planner.yaml within the package of ros2 xarm driver but how does my node know where to find that yaml file etc.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks